# This sequence $\sqrt {a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a...}}}}$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove that this sequence $(x_n)$, where $x_1 =\sqrt a$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{a +x_n}$ has a limit, then I would like to find the limit of

$L=\sqrt {a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a...}}}}$

It's easy to find this limit and prove that this sequence is monotone (induction over $\mathbb N$). What I found difficult is prove that this sequence is bounded.

I need help in this part.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $a\ge1$, we have $x_1=\sqrt{a}\le a<2a$ and by mathematical induction,
$$x_{n+1}^2 = a + x_n < a+2a=3a < 4a^2\ \Rightarrow\ x_{n+1}<2a.$$ When $a<1$, the sequence is dominated by the analogous sequence with $a=1$ and hence it is bounded.

Comment: I didn't understand, when a=2, we have $\sqrt {2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2…}}}}$, it isn't a constant sequence.

Comment: @user42912 Oops, I misread the question. Thanks for pointing out the error. Will delete this answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: no problem, thank you for trying to help me :)

Comment: @user42912 I've tried to fix the proof. Please see if it's OK now.

Comment: it seems ok! thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If the limit exists, it is obvious to see that 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n$$
So lets call the limit $x$ than 
$$x=\sqrt{a+x}$$
For the bound, i would use banach fix point theorem. The fix point theorem together with the fact, that the root is a strict contraction. So we know 
$$x_1\leq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{\sqrt{a}}$$ For $a$ sufficiently large $a$ will be a upper bound and $0$ a lower bound. For $a$ not sufficiently large we don't need a proof, since we know it is lower bounded by $0$  and monotone increasing, so we can take the upper bound of the sufficiently large $a$ (monotonicity of the root).

Comment: How would you use this theorem? I couldn't figure out how to apply in this question.

Comment: the root is a strict contraction

Comment: I didn't understand, please add a little bit more information in your answer. Thank you very much

Comment: better now ? sry if it was to short

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand yet. Maybe I don't have the maturity to understand your answer yet. Anyway, thank your for trying to help me.

Comment: How to show the root operation is a strict contraction mapping?

Comment: After scaling you only need to prove $1-|x|\leq\sqrt{(1+x)} \leq 1+|x|$ (you can do it over the relative condition too, which is $\frac{1}{2}$